# Migration Class CreateSessionTable error 301

Tags: laravel-4

i accidentally execute php artisan migrate:session.
and it migrated, i delete the file createSessionTable,
and now i try to execute php artisan migrate:reset and the migrator in laravel still searching for CreateSessionTable.

i already use composer dump-autoload
composer dumpautoload
php artisan dump-autoload
php artisan dumpautoload
composer update // doesn't resolve the problem

it doesn't work anymore.
do you encounter it?

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted the migration file you have two options:

1) Create a new one with the same name 2014_0000_create_session_table.php (the numbers doesn't really matter in this case, and rollback with it, you don't really need to create things in those methods (but you better create a drop method to drop that sessions table for you), you just need the class CreateSessionTable to be available for Laravel. After creating that file you'll need to `composer dump`.

2) Manually delete the line in the migrations table and also drop the sessions table.

You can also delete all your tables manually and all records on migrations file and then migrate again.